# Warning regarding sesion_start

Tags: php, session-cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php headers already sent error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319207/php-headers-already-sent-error)

I've this warning. How can I fix it?

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at C:\AppServ\www\PhpProject1\login.php:2) in C:\AppServ\www\PhpProject1\controller\login.controller.php on line 2

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at C:\AppServ\www\PhpProject1\login.php:2) in C:\AppServ\www\PhpProject1\controller\login.controller.php on line 2
```

Comment: This has been answered so many time. Please [search for “headers already sent”](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=headers+already+sent).

Comment: The headers_sent function is a good place to start debugging these errors:  http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php

Answer (score 1):

paste session_start(); in the first line

Comment: @soad: But you may have a Unicode Byte-Order Mark before it. Save your PHP file as something other than Unicode.

Comment: @Soad:thank you, if you're happy could you mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You should also be aware that saving your files in the wrong encoding can produce this error.

http://forums.iis.net/t/1171412.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Session needs to be started before ANY content is printed out.
You're echoing something  earlier or simply printing something outside PHP tags.

Move your session_start before those print outs. This concerns print outs from ALL your files.
It says you even where you've printed stuff out.

> output started at C:\AppServ\www\PhpProject1\login.php:2

Comment: Only if a cookie for the session ID or a HTTP cache limiter is used.