# Why am I getting this "Headers already sent" error?

Tags: php, header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php headers already sent error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319207/php-headers-already-sent-error)

I have tried every thing to solve it, but this thig just wont go away.

Here is what I'm doing

```
if($query)
{
header("location:cool.php");
exit();
}
```

even though $query is executed, an issue with header.

thanks.

Comment: what is the code before that?

Comment: 5000+ results for [“Headers already sent” error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%E2%80%9CHeaders+already+sent%E2%80%9D+error%3F)

Answer (score 3):

ANY output will need headers sent, so any output will get you this error.

Common problems:

- whitespace (e.g. before the `<?php` )
- errors / exceptions
- debugging echos/var_dumps
- warnings from php (deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

You will get that error of you have any (I mean **ANY**) output beforehand

Comment: even with this?? echo mysqli_error($connect);

Comment: @steve, do you have **ANYTHING** outputted to the page?

Comment: yes, anything. any output. thats what the word **ANYTHING** means. it means anything

Comment: Yes even with this it's possible. `echo mysqli_error($connect);` is not complete PHP code. Maybe you have a blank or carriage return right before the opening tag, for example: `_<?php echo mysqli_error($connect);?>`. Or your code is included by other code and outputs s/t before including. etc.

Comment: @steve absolutely **ANY** output, e.g. any line of code starting with `echo` or any functions that might send output to the browser before your call to `header` will cause the error.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that $query is not outputting any data, other wise you'll get your error.

If not check to make sure NO data is being output before hand.