# Php Session header already send error

Tags: php, session, header

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php headers already sent error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319207/php-headers-already-sent-error)

I have attached my code which am using for a very basic login in php. It giving an error

> Cannot send session cookie - headers
>   already sent by (output started at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\netsentries\f\includes\functions.php:1)

```
   <?php 
    if (!isset($_POST['username'])) {
    ?>
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <form action="" method="post">
    Username<br/>
    <input name="username" type="text" /><br/>
    Password<br/>
    <input name="password" type="password" /><br/>
    <input name="" type="submit" /><br/>
    </form>
    <?php
    }
     else 
    { 
    include('includes/config.php');

    $data['username']= $_POST['username'];
    $data['password']= md5($_POST['password']);

    connect($db_name,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_host);

    $query= "select * from user where username='" . $data['username'] . "' AND password='" . $data['password'] . "'";

        $result=mysql_query($query);
        //check that at least one row was returned
        $rowCheck = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if($rowCheck > 0)
        {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
            session_start();
            session_register($data['username']);
            //successful login code will go here...
            //echo 'Logged in!'; 
            }
        }
        else
        {
        echo "Failed!";
        }



    }
    ?>
```

Am not able to find out the problem

Comment: The error is coming from the file C:\xampp\htdocs\netsentries\f\includes\functions.php:1 . Are you sure you don't have a call to the header() function in that file?

Comment: What is in `include('includes/config.php');`?

Comment: Check if C:\xampp\htdocs\netsentries\f\includes\functions.php is outputting anything.

Comment: Check for BOM. Never save with BOM. - which editor are you using?

Comment: did you actually read the error??
http://www.google.com/search?q=Cannot+send+session+cookie+-+headers+already+sent+by

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't `session_start` after you've outputted any HTML at all. Move the `session_start` call up to the top, and keep a variable for what to echo later. Anything not in `<?php ?>` counts, even your include file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put session_start() before anything outputs on the page.

```
 <?php
session_start(); 
if (!isset($_POST['username'])) {
?>
<h3>Login</h3>
<form action="" method="post">
Username<br/>
<input name="username" type="text" /><br/>
Password<br/>
<input name="password" type="password" /><br/>
<input name="" type="submit" /><br/>
</form>
<?php
}
 else 
{ 
include('includes/config.php');

$data['username']= $_POST['username'];
$data['password']= md5($_POST['password']);

connect($db_name,$db_user,$db_pass,$db_host);

$query= "select * from user where username='" . $data['username'] . "' AND password='" . $data['password'] . "'";

    $result=mysql_query($query);
    //check that at least one row was returned
    $rowCheck = mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($rowCheck > 0)
    {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
        session_register($data['username']);
        //successful login code will go here...
        //echo 'Logged in!'; 
        }
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Failed!";
    }



}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you were trying to use any function that modifies the header (like `header` or `session_start`), you need to make sure that **nothing** was outputting beforehand, even whitespace -- or else you will get that error.

Answer (score 2):

Halfway down you're having

```
session_start();
```

But you don't want any output before that. And you have -in the very least- this allready sent:

```
   <h3>Login</h3>
    <form action="" method="post">
    Username<br/>
    <input name="username" type="text" /><br/>
    Password<br/>
    <input name="password" type="password" /><br/>
    <input name="" type="submit" /><br/>
    </form>
```

PUt the session on the top :D

Answer (score 1):

```
include('includes/config.php');
```

look for white space in that file.

in particular after the ?> at the end of the file there is often white space.

so omit the closing ?> at the end of your files.

Comment: +1 for omit the closing `?>` - a handy tip, often overlooked.

Comment: but the advice marramgrass gave is also good. the other way of fixing it :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is absolutely nothing being output before your session call - even whitespace. (See Pekka's comment :) )